# I/0 error on external hard drive (owncloud server)

Tags: hard-drive, usb, debian, external-hard-drive, raspberry-pi

I have an owncloud server setup on a raspberry pi with debian. As a mass storage I use a [Intenso 500 GB USB drive](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005QNRP4A) which is plugged into a [LogiLink USB hub](http://www.amazon.de/LogiLink-4-Port-Hub-Netzteil-schwarz/dp/B003ECC6O4/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1387724340&sr=8-6&keywords=logilink) because the Raspberry pi can't power the USB drive itself. 
When I boot the Raspi everything works just fine and it will start synchronizing my files, but after approx. 1h I get the following error:

```
Data directory (/media/usb1/owncloud/data) not writable by ownCloud
Permissions can usually be fixed by giving the webserver write access to the ownCloud directory
```

When I try to access the drive via ssh I get

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ls /media/usb1
ls: reading directory /media/usb1: Input/output error
```

And it doesn't matter whether I try it as root or not.

I looked into my syslog and found, that it mounted and unmounted the drive several times before

```
Dec 22 13:13:51 thecabbage kernel: [    2.610218] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=9512
Dec 22 13:13:51 thecabbage kernel: [    2.618633] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
Dec 22 13:13:51 thecabbage kernel: [    2.628570] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
Dec 22 13:13:51 thecabbage kernel: [    2.634990] hub 1-1:1.0: 3 ports detected
Dec 22 13:13:51 thecabbage kernel: [    2.919641] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using dwc_otg
Dec 22 13:13:51 thecabbage kernel: [    3.039878] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=ec00
Dec 22 13:13:51 thecabbage kernel: [    3.048428] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
Dec 22 13:13:51 thecabbage kernel: [    3.062073] smsc95xx v1.0.4
Dec 22 13:13:51 thecabbage kernel: [    3.125592] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: register 'smsc95xx' at usb-bcm2708_usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet, b8:27:eb:b3:7a:73
Dec 22 13:13:51 thecabbage kernel: [    3.249669] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
Dec 22 13:13:51 thecabbage kernel: [    3.381573] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0608
Dec 22 13:13:51 thecabbage kernel: [    3.396388] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
Dec 22 13:13:51 thecabbage kernel: [    3.410539] usb 1-1.2: Product: USB2.0 Hub
Dec 22 13:13:51 thecabbage kernel: [    3.422131] hub 1-1.2:1.0: USB hub found
Dec 22 13:13:51 thecabbage kernel: [    3.430220] hub 1-1.2:1.0: 4 ports detected
Dec 22 13:13:51 thecabbage kernel: [    3.719824] usb 1-1.2.1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
Dec 22 13:13:51 thecabbage kernel: [    3.841101] usb 1-1.2.1: New USB device found, idVendor=13fd, idProduct=1840
Dec 22 13:13:51 thecabbage kernel: [    3.859642] usb 1-1.2.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Dec 22 13:13:51 thecabbage kernel: [    3.871457] usb 1-1.2.1: Product: USB 2.0 Drive
Dec 22 13:13:51 thecabbage kernel: [    3.877793] usb 1-1.2.1: Manufacturer: PI-239
Dec 22 13:13:51 thecabbage kernel: [    3.884178] usb 1-1.2.1: SerialNumber: 533252594A39434431313731
Dec 22 13:13:51 thecabbage kernel: [    3.892819] usb-storage 1-1.2.1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Dec 22 13:13:51 thecabbage kernel: [    3.901643] scsi0 : usb-storage 1-1.2.1:1.0
Dec 22 13:13:51 thecabbage kernel: [    4.900648] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     PI-239   USB 2.0 Drive    1.08 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
Dec 22 13:13:51 thecabbage kernel: [    4.933311] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/465 GiB)
Dec 22 13:13:51 thecabbage kernel: [    4.963305] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
Dec 22 13:13:51 thecabbage kernel: [    4.989392] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
Dec 22 13:13:51 thecabbage kernel: [    4.990187] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
Dec 22 13:13:51 thecabbage kernel: [    4.997069] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
Dec 22 13:13:51 thecabbage kernel: [    5.035068] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
Dec 22 13:13:51 thecabbage kernel: [    5.059342] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
Dec 22 13:13:51 thecabbage kernel: [    5.089366]  sda: sda1
Dec 22 13:13:51 thecabbage kernel: [    5.096949] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
Dec 22 13:13:51 thecabbage kernel: [    5.113466] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
Dec 22 13:13:51 thecabbage kernel: [    5.140575] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
Dec 22 13:13:51 thecabbage kernel: [    6.302336] bcm2708-i2s bcm2708-i2s.0: Failed to create debugfs directory
Dec 22 13:13:51 thecabbage kernel: [   15.139041] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
Dec 22 13:13:51 thecabbage kernel: [   15.627170] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
Dec 22 13:13:51 thecabbage kernel: [   24.054213] EXT4-fs (sda1): recovery complete
Dec 22 13:13:51 thecabbage kernel: [   24.063171] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

But it still worked at that time. After roughly 1 hour the following error appeared:

```
Dec 22 14:33:12 thecabbage kernel: [  470.843026] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 4
Dec 22 14:33:12 thecabbage kernel: [  470.843063] usb 1-1.2.1: USB disconnect, device number 5
Dec 22 14:33:12 thecabbage kernel: [  470.853453] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 38034432
Dec 22 14:33:12 thecabbage kernel: [  470.853499] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 38034433
Dec 22 14:33:12 thecabbage kernel: [  470.853519] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 38034434
Dec 22 14:33:12 thecabbage kernel: [  470.853535] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 38034435
Dec 22 14:33:12 thecabbage kernel: [  470.853551] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 38034436
Dec 22 14:33:12 thecabbage kernel: [  470.853567] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 38034437
Dec 22 14:33:12 thecabbage kernel: [  470.853583] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 38034438
Dec 22 14:33:12 thecabbage kernel: [  470.853599] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 38034439
Dec 22 14:33:12 thecabbage kernel: [  470.853614] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 38034440
Dec 22 14:33:12 thecabbage kernel: [  470.853632] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 38034441
Dec 22 14:33:12 thecabbage kernel: [  470.853648] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 38034442
Dec 22 14:33:12 thecabbage kernel: [  470.853665] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 38034443
Dec 22 14:33:12 thecabbage kernel: [  470.853681] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 38034444
Dec 22 14:33:12 thecabbage kernel: [  470.853698] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 38034445
Dec 22 14:33:12 thecabbage kernel: [  470.853713] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 38034446
Dec 22 14:33:12 thecabbage kernel: [  470.853729] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 38034447
Dec 22 14:33:12 thecabbage kernel: [  470.853746] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 38034448q
```

Anybody an idea what could cause this error? My suspect is the USB hub and the power management, but I don't know how to check that. Maybe the hard drive is defect? It is mounted according to /etc/fstab

```
UUID=915a8f36-5c7d-40e3-a451-a3babb0fa610       /media/usb1     ext4    defaults          0       0
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: I would say bad sectors.  Run mhdd on it and turn REMAP on.

Comment: sorry couldn't find mhdd for linux. is it windows only or is there at least an aquivalent?

Comment: http://hddguru.com/software/2005.10.02-MHDD/   Get the ISO burn it to CD or make a bootable USB stick.

Comment: Have a look at `hdparm` as it may be your disk spinning down... `hdparm -S 0` should disable spindown...